# k8s expose virtual service with istio

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I’ve download the Prometheus helm chart
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus

and deploy it to our cluster `as-is` and I was **able to access prom ui** via port-forwarding.

As we are using `istio` I want to configure it to access with host (lik external IP ) and I configure the following but it doesn’t work for me.

I mean if I put the host I don’t get anything in the browser, any idea what could be missing here ?

I **dont** see any `exteranal-ip` when running `kubectl get svc -n mon` ,

just internal-ip which doesnt help to our needs.

gateway.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: http-gateway
  namespace: mon
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - hosts: mo-gateway.web-system.svc.cluster.local
      port:
        name: https-monitoring
        number: 443
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        privateKey: /etc/istio/sa-tls/tls.key
        serverCertificate: /etc/istio/sa-tls/tls.crt
```

virtual_service.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prom-virtualservice
  namespace: mon
spec:
  hosts:
    -  mo-gateway.web-system.svc.cluster.locall
  gateways:
    - http-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /prometheus
      route:
        - destination:
            host: prometheus-server
            port:
              number: 80
```

Any idea why it doesnt works ?

Btw, If I just change the type of Prometheus to use [LoadBalancer](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/values.yaml#L851) it work, I was able to get `external-ip` and use it but not on istio

istio is up-and-running ...

Comment: did you deploy the actual gateway? not the gateway resource, but the actual envoy gateway

Comment: @4c74356b41 - yes we have istio up and running under namespace istio-system

Comment: @4c74356b41 we have istio-ingressgateway istio-init pods etc under istio-system

Comment: well, check ingress gateway logs, check envoy config on the gateway

Comment: can you please provide info how ? does my config look right ?

Comment: "locall" in the virtual service definition has an extra "l" at the end; I'm not sure if this is an error copying into SO, but if that's your actual file, that mismatch could be a problem.  You won't see any change in your Service objects and have to contact the ingress gateway from outside the cluster.

Comment: @DavidMaze - this is just a type in the question, I've same host exactly without dobule l ... any idea what could be the reason or how to monitor it ?

Comment: What is  your infrastructure? Is your prometheus in injected namespace?